# iPhone: Verticle alignment for Numbers in Label in Landscape mode

Tags: iphone, uilabel, vertical-alignment

I am trying to align label text vertically aligned for my iPhone application Timer. Basically it's a game application and timer value appears in MM:SS format in label in landscape mode. When I have added label and tried to set this value it appears like image 1 which is not correct. I found from many threads that you can set multiple line and make label width as one char but it appears like image 2 which is also wrong. I want my timer value to appear as image 3. Could anyone please tell me how could I achieve it?

Thanks.

[Added real picture of what I am trying to do]

[image]

[image: The timer in land scape mode....not correct]

[image: The timer when I set multiple lines for each digit...]

[image: I want this is to happen...]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you really want to get.

Comment: Hi Eiko, please see the iPhone screen shot. I want the left bottom corner lable text appear verticle aligned. Tring Amit's suggestion of Transformation but still not able to get exactly verticle aligned.

Comment: Code? I have added label in my application and set the text. By default it appears as I the given in iPhone screen shot. I want them to appear vertically aligned like the fourth(last) image in my question.

Comment: What is wrong with rotating the whole label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    CGAffineTransform transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(300);//change angle according.
    transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-300);//change angle according.
    lbl.transform=transform;
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, it doesn't appear exactly what I am trying to achive but close. See the screen shot I have added. I tried changing angles but no luck.

Comment: Perfect.Thanks. I am wondering why the angle is 300 when theoretically it should be 180?

Comment: Angle is not in degree but in radians.
u can have (90.0f * M_PI / 180.0f) this for first transform & comment sencond transform.